# Put the values of TextInput in array in React Native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, native

I wanted to put the values ​​of multiple textinputs in an array dynamically in React native. When I try with onChangeText it puts all the letters separately in the array and not the word I typed. Here is my code. Can someone help me? Thank you.

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      body: '',
      isSending: false,
      refreshing: false,
      title: '',
      options: []
   }
```

TextInput:

```
 <TextInput
    style={[styles.TextInput, {marginTop: 10}]}
    placeholder={'Value1'}
    onChangeText={options => this.setState({options})}
 />
 <TextInput
    style={[styles.TextInput, {marginTop: 5}]}
    placeholder={'Value2'}
    onChangeText={options => this.setState({...options})}
 />
 <TextInput
    style={[styles.TextInput, {marginTop: 5}]}
    placeholder={'Value3'}
    onChangeText={options => this.setState({...options})}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to submit the word that you typed and store value for each input 
separately not in array but in object. So you can do something like this:

this.state = {
   options: {
       foo: '',
       bar: '',
       baz: ''
   }
};

<TextInput
   name="foo"
   onEndEditing={
     e => this.setState({
       options: { ...this.state.options, foo: e.nativeEvent.text }
     })
   }
/>

<TextInput
   name="bar"
   onEndEditing={
     e => this.setState({
       options: { ...this.state.options, bar: e.nativeEvent.text }
     })
   }
/>

<TextInput
   name="baz"
   onEndEditing={
     e => this.setState({
       options: { ...this.state.options, baz: e.nativeEvent.text }
     })
   }
/>
```